# Dump MySQL Schema with first 1000 records of each table

Tags: mysql

Any way to dump the schema for a database, but only keep the first 1000 records of each table?

I want to do this in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` with an offset like this:

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000, 18446744073709551615;
```

Limit on 1000 so it wont select the first 1000 records and the large number after it, is so it select ALL records after the 1000, when you don't excactly know how much records you have.